# Optional argument removed with rest operator in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I created an utility function that takes an object as an argument and is immediately destructured. `arg` is a must inside a function, but it should not by obligatory.

```
export const doSomething = ({ arg, ...rest }) => {
  // BODY OF THE FUNCTION
};
```

I want this to be generic - so if in the future someone would like to use it - he can do it even with an object without `arg` property. When I try it with an object like:

```
{
  a: "a",
  b: "b",
  c: "c",
};
```

I get an error:

> Property 'arg' is missing in type '{ a: string; b: string; c: string;
> }' but required in type '{ [x: string]: any; arg: any; }'.ts(2345)

Comment: So in your case, arg should take the value of a?

Comment: That's a TypeScript errors. If you are using TypeScript say so, don't claim it is JS.

Comment: Your function doesn't have any types on it at all, so you're immediately going to have a problem with `arg` (at least). Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally both in the question and as an example on [the TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play).

Comment: What do you mean by *"`arg` is a must inside a function, but it should not by obligatory"*?

Comment: "arg is a must inside a function, but it should not by obligatory" I'm confused.

Answer (score 1):

> `arg` is a must inside a function, but it should not by obligatory.

As best I can make out, you mean that the function needs `arg`, but it doesn't need to be supplied by the caller. That means you need a default value for it. You can supply that in the destructuring:

```typescript
export const doSomething = ({ arg = "some default value", ...rest }) => {
  // BODY OF THE FUNCTION
};
```

The default also generally makes it possible for TypeScript to infer the type for `arg`, though in some cases you may need to specify it.

You'll still need to define a type for `rest` (in the worst case, `any[]`, but avoid `any` if you possibly can).

Answer (score 0):

You should do your operation inside the function and pass default `arg` value:

```
export const doSomething = (obj) => {
  const { arg = SOME_DEFAULT_VALUE, rest } = obj;

  // BODY OF THE FUNCTION
};
```

Comment: Why? That's basically the same thing.

Comment: but here TS won't complain

Comment: Done correctly in TS, it won't complain about destructuring in the parameter list, either.

Comment: try calling doSomething({a:'b'}) - in my case it complained with the example case, after my change it's OK

Comment: That's because of the default value, not because you moved the destructuring.

Answer (score 0):

You can make `arg` optional:

```
export const doSomething = ({ arg, ...rest }: { [k: string]: any; arg?: any; }) => {
  // BODY OF THE FUNCTION
};
```

In that case, if `arg` doesn't exist in the object, `arg` will be `undefined`. If you prefer another value instead of `undefined`, give it a default value:

```
export const doSomething = ({ arg = "nonexistent", ...rest }: { [k: string]: any; arg?: any; }) => {
  // BODY OF THE FUNCTION
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Predefine a `type/interface` for the function input (you should change the `any` type inside the `interface` to be more specific), this way you make sure TypeScript and others know the `arg` is optional, and also be able to use the type power of TypeScript :

```
interface Param {
    arg?: any
}

const doSomething = (param: Param) => {
    let {arg, ...rest} = param;
    // Do your stuff
    console.log(arg);
};
```